# Timer with arcade python

Tags: python-3.x, arcade

I wanted to make a visual timer in python but couldn't find any graphic libraries so I used arcade to do the job but I think there is something I'm not getting.
All I have so far :

```
import time

SCREEN_WIDTH = 600
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
arcade.open_window(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "Program test")

arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.WHITE)


arcade.start_render()

mid_x = SCREEN_WIDTH/2
mid_y = SCREEN_HEIGHT/2

def cur_time(self):
    arcade.draw_text(str(c_tim),start_x,start_y,arcade.color.BLACK)

def sc(self):
    arcade.draw_rectangle_filled(mid_y,mid_y,600,600,arcade.color.BLACK)
    arcade.draw_rectangle_filled(mid_y,mid_y,600,600,arcade.color.WHITE)

start_x = 100
start_y = 100
c_tim = 10


while True:
    cur_time
    time.sleep(1)
    sc
    arcade.get_projection()



arcade.finish_render()

arcade.run()
```

Comment: `def cur_time(self):` is supposed to be a member of a _class_. Also, `<object name>.cur_time()` instead of `cur_time`.

Comment: Same goes to the <object name>.sc() instead of sc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you could use a Tkinter GUI for it. I don't have the time right now to code it for you, but arcade isn't designed for that kind of thing. It's for making 2D games generally not creating nice timers. Just use tkinter gui.

Answer (score 1):

Simple timer with `arcade`:

```
import time
import arcade
import datetime

class Timer(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(600, 400, 'Arcade Timer')
        self.time = None

    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.start_render()
        if self.time:
            text = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=time.time()-self.time))
        else:
            text = 'Click to start timer!'

        arcade.draw_text(text, 300, 200, arcade.color.RED, 40, anchor_x='center')

    def on_mouse_release(self, x, y, button, key_modifiers):
        self.time = time.time() if not self.time else None

Timer()
arcade.run()
```

Example run:

[image]